# import and export of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
//D:/workspace/www/hello-world/src/data/articles.js   

const articles = [
    {"title": "title1","content": "content1"},
    {"title": "title2","content": "content2"},
    {"title": "title3","content": "content3"}]
```

```
//D:/workspace/www/nodejs_scripts/test.js     

import articles from '../hello-world/src/data/articles.js';
console.log(articles);
```

```
//D:/workspace/www/nodejs_scripts/package.json    

{
  "type": "module"
}
```

run `test.js`

```
D:\workspace\www\nodejs_scripts
λ node -v
v12.11.1

D:\workspace\www\nodejs_scripts
λ node --experimental-modules test.js
(node:7756) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
{}
```

**Question:**
How to get the data of `articles.js`?

Comment: try add `export default articles` at last line of D:/workspace/www/hello-world/src/data/articles.js

Answer (score 3):

In order to import something first you need to export it. I hope code below will solve your problem.

```
const articles = [
    {"title": "title1","content": "content1"},
    {"title": "title2","content": "content2"},
    {"title": "title3","content": "content3"}]

module.exports = {
    articles
}
```

The code in other file should work fine after exporting the articles constant.

Comment: it's need to be default. If you don't export default, you need to import { articles } from '..../js'

Answer (score 0):

You should use `require` rather than `import` in a NodeJS environment. Also you need to `export` your array:

```
//D:/workspace/www/hello-world/src/data/articles.js   

const articles = [
    {"title": "title1","content": "content1"},
    {"title": "title2","content": "content2"},
    {"title": "title3","content": "content3"}]

module.exports = {
    articles
}
```

And then use `require`:

```
//D:/workspace/www/nodejs_scripts/test.js     

const articles = require('../hello-world/src/data/articles.js');
console.log(articles);
```

Comment: They are using `--experimental-modules ` so ES6 modules are supported

Comment: You're right - I missed that. Perhaps he just needs to export via modules syntax and then it'll all be fine.

Answer (score -1):

you need to export the articles variable as default export

```
//D:/workspace/www/hello-world/src/data/articles.js   

const articles = [
    {"title": "title1","content": "content1"},
    {"title": "title2","content": "content2"},
    {"title": "title3","content": "content3"}]

export default articles
```

you can read more about it https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: it's actually need to be default. If you don't export default, you need to `import { articles } from '..../js'`